# How can I format a flash drive using terminal emulator?

Tags: cyanogenmod, terminal, usb-host-mode, formatting, huawei-u8160

I have a Huawei u8160 running Cyanogenmod 7.2.

I've recently installed the usb host package and some time then I successfully activated the usb host mode.

after that I needed to format a flash drive using ONLY my phone.

my phone doesn't recognize thumb drives, but I mount them on /mnt/sdcard/data folder.

So I wanted to know if there's any command in the terminal emulator that can format a usb drive.

**NOTE:** I've already tried "mkfs" command it doesn't exist,I won't accept answers telling me to format it on my PC.

Comment: Did you try `mke2fs` (or, with full path, `/system/bin/mke2fs` -- maybe in a different place on your phone)? There are also `/system/xbin/mkfs.ext2`, `/system/xbin/mkfs.minix`, and `/system/xbin/mkfs.vfat` -- most likely you are looking for the last one ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are native programs available on Android for creating file systems, and in most cases they reside in a directory below `/system` (my Motorola Droid 2 e.g. has them in `/system/xbin`. Depending on the file system you want to create, you can chose between:

- `mkfs.ext2`
- `mkfs.minix` (unlikely you want that -- and it might even be not available with your ROM)
- `mkfs.vfat`

As the latter is probably what you want, some closer explanation on its options here:

```
mkfs.vfat [-v] [-n LABEL] BLOCKDEV [KBYTES]
```

What do those options stand for?

- `-v`: Generate verbose output (reporting)
- `-n Label`: Give the file system a name
- `BLOCKDEV`: the file system you want to format
- `KBYTES`: probably the block size (I'm not 100% sure with this)

So the minimal thing to do would be:

```
mkfs.vfat -v /dev/block/uba1
```

(provided your drive to format is available as `/dev/block/uba1` on your system). One more example, giving the file system a name:

```
mkfs.vfat -v -n MyNewDisk /dev/block/uba1
```

It should report success then -- or an error if it failed.

**EDIT:** On some systems, the `mkfs` commands seem to be part of the `busybox` binaries -- which you can recognize with a full directory listing, e.g.

```
ls -l /system/xbin | grep mkfs
```

It should show them as "symbolic links" pointing to busybox then. In this case, you can optionally run them via busybox:

```
busybox mkfs.vfat
```

should show you the syntax then (thanks to ce4 for pointing this out -- credits to him ;) ).

Answer (score -2):

The command to format through adb/terminal emulator is simply `format`.

Comment: format : not found

Comment: Well that's unusual. I thought all adb commands worked in a terminal emulator. I'll keep looking.

Comment: don't bother yourself looking for it the right answer was already chosen

Comment: Oh, I thought mkfs didn't exist either... Or I guess the symlink fixed that.

Comment: it existed but in busybox that's why I thought it didn't exist at all

Comment: @SaintWacko always good to have an unpacked Nandroid backup around to check with xD