# Does Android support the EXT (filesystem) for removable storage cards?

Tags: file-system, ext4, ext2, ext3

As the subject indicates, does Android support any of the Extended File Systems ("ext", "ext2", "ext3" and "ext4") for removable storage cards (such as Micro SDXC storage cards)?

Android is a Linux-based operating system, so surely such filesystems would be supported?

My question relates to both Android 4.4-4.4.4 ("KitKat") and Android 5.0-5.1.1 ("Lollipop"), as I am just about to buy the Sony Xperia Z Ultra which runs the former, but has an upgrade available for "Lollipop"...

The reason I ask is because Extended File Systems have a number of distinct advantages over Microsoft filesystems, and I do not use Microsoft Windows-based operating systems at all (well, at work I do - but personal stuff can't be used with their computers...), so it's only logical to utilize Extended Filesystems where possible, for the technical advantages.

Comment: Related -- http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/39610/how-to-format-storage-sdcard0-in-ext4 and http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/4497/can-i-use-ext4-on-my-sd-card-in-a-non-rooted-phone

Comment: This site has ext tags with Q/A associated with them, namely: [tag:ext2], [tag:ext3] and [tag:ext4]. Unfortunately, I couldn't find the support specific to your device. As you said, filesystems should be supported. I agree but certain devices doesn't allow SD card formatted with ext4. I have one such godforsaken device.

Comment: Update: This [thread](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2272857) on XDA mentioned an app named [Xperia SD Card mounter](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.doomlord.xperiasdcardmounter)(Z ultra supported). It seems that ext4 works fine with internal storage as per the comments but nothing concrete can be said about external ones. I suggest contacting the thread owner for specific details. Play Store shows that the last update to this app was in June, 2014. I wonder about the support for Lollipop.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it does support ext4 from what I gather from other sites and I am doing it right now on my own card.

Comment: but as with anything android, it varies widely with manufacturer and version.

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts! Consider adding links to the sites you've read and include essential parts of them to backup your answer and make it more reliable :)

Comment: my usb pens with ext4 works on kitkat 4.4 , but not with  android marshmallow 6.0.1 , due an selinux restriction I guess

Comment: This uninformed answer is problematic.